# Htaccess redirect with cakePHP

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a cakePHP app working at `http://domain1.com/domain2`, and want to point `http://domain2.com/` to this application.

I have done this change the document root of `domain2` to `public_html/domain2`, but, when I go to: `domain2.com` all css, javascript and images are not loaded, with a message saying controller not found.

What I can do?

All domains have a folder with their domains without the TLD at domain1.com, I think if I create a htaccess and get the domain without TLD, and finally change rewriteBase, will work as expected, but don't know how to do this.

Current htaccess of `domain2`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding an htaccess file in domain2's document root with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|bmp|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?domain2/(.*) /$1 [L,PT]
```

This should remove the `domain2` part of the links.

Comment: I already have a htaccess, see my update. I don't know how to merge the last line, which is what do the "magic". Should be `RewriteRule ^/?domain2/(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`?

Comment: @GabrielSantos Add the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` lines from my answer *just under* the `RewriteBase` from the rules you already have. If you are still having issues, try adding a `R=301` in the square brackets so they look like: `[L,R=301]`.

Comment: Worked, but, my images, css and js are broken.